# Can we cast from string or char datatype to int (or numeric) in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, casting, etl, derived-column

I find this little challenging. I have source table and destination table.

Source table has one of the column with char datatype with length of 2.
Destination table has one of the column with int datatype.

Task is to migrate data from source to destination using SSIS package. And in that process I am using derived column transform to handle this conversion.

Column in Source table has value as "01" or "02" or "03". Whereas destination column having int datatype cannot be mapped with source column. As int only recognizes "1". **I want 1 or 2 or 3 only and omit 0 in destination column.**

I tried few things as below.

**Try #1:**

```
SUBSTRING(COLNAME, 2, 1)
```

This gives me "1" from "01" but when I do

```
(DT_R4) SUBSTRING(COLNAME, 2, 1 )
```

It fails me outright.

**Try #2:**

I try to cast like below.

```
(DT_DECIMAL, 2)(DT_R4) SUBSTRING(COLNAME, 2, 1 )
```

That did not work as well.

If there is a way out, I appreciate any direction here.

Comment: What about `(DT_DECIMAL, 2) COLNAME`? I don't have access to SSIS at the moment, but I'm pretty confident that it'll be happy with that. If you then need it as a real, rather than a decimal, then do `(DT_R4)((DT_DECIMAL, 2) COLNAME)`.

Comment: @Larnu why not `(DT_I4)`, also the issue may be caused by some empty or NULL values

Comment: I appreciate your hint here @Larnu. As I really intended to cast to integer datatype, your second took me closer to resolve. Upvoted. And @Hadi, Thank you for sharing the extended solution. That is perfect to cover my scenario when source column has `NULL` values. And yes as it is destination type is integer, it is better to cast using `(DT_I4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the destination column in of type Integer `DT_I4` then you should use the following expression in the derived column:

```
(DT_I4)[SourceColumn]
```

Also check for `Null`s and Empty strings:

```
ISNULL([SourceColumn]) ? NULL(DT_I4): ([SourceColumn] == "" ? NULL(DT_I4): (DT_I4)[SourceColumn])
```

Comment: That's completely feasible and accommodating to the scenario asked. This is perfect resolution. Upvoted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to directly connect source and destination columns without using the data conversion or derived column transformation? I think It should implicitly convert from char to Integer if all the data in the source table are numbers though the data type is char.

Comment: If the source column contains an empty string ( != NULL) then it will throw an exception.